# I'm having trouble describing a series of events

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm having trouble describing a series of events. I think speaking naturally is important but I don't think speaking diversely is not important. So I've made as much sentences as possible. I think #1 is the most natural one. but I'd like to know if I can use the other ones without changing meaning.

> 1. I wake up at 10 A.M and I get up about 30 minutes later.
> 2. I wake up at 10 A.M and I get up about 30 minutes after I wake up.
> 3. I wake up at 10 A.M. but I don't get up until about 30 minutes have passed.
> 4. I wake up at 10 A.M. and it's about 30 minutes later that I get up.
> 5. I wake up at 10 A.M. and it's about 30 minutes after I wake up that I get up.
> 6. I wake up at 10 A.M. and it's not until about 30 minutes have passed that I get up.

Comment: Though some sentences are quite wordy and the first one is probably the most idiomatic one, all of your sentences are grammatically correct and have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, 3, 4, and 6 are fine. My preference would be for 1.

2 and 5 aren't strictly wrong, but the second use of "I wake up" in each makes them clumsy. You could improve them by replacing "after I wake up" with "afterwards".